# How can I change the language settings of virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

Yesterday, I downloaded and installed the Oracle VM Virtual Box on my PC but the UI language is Danish. 
Can anyone guide me through the process of changing the UI language to English? I have tried clicking the settings button but it is inactive.

Comment: This question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's pretty easy:

1. Open VirtualBox
2. In the main menu, open the first tag (File), and select the 4th option (Configuration/Preferences). In my VirtualBox, you can go directly there with Ctrl+G.
3. Once you are in the Configuration menu, in the left bar, select the one where a world image is shown (Language).
4. Select the language you want.

P.D. If you get lost in any step because of the language of the menu, you can go to google traductor and translate the part you don't understand and change the language then.

Hope it works!

Comment: Thanks for your response. At first I was lost because of the language but I was finally able to get it right.

Comment: CTRL+G all the way :) The menu location changed since this answer. It's now first option.

Comment: Worked on V 6.01

Answer (score 3):

There are only three options in VB5. The language settings are now in:
VirtualBox -> Preferences -> Language

Comment: And in case it is a foreign language, it is the first menu entry and the shortcut is ctrl + G, then click the "world" globe icon.